# "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" despite existence check

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-9.4, upsert

On PostgreSQL 9.4.

I was surprised to see that error in our server logs, pinpointed to the sole statement inside a pl/pgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_upsert(
    intype text,
    invalue text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

  WITH upsert AS
  (
    UPDATE mytable
      SET count = count + 1
    WHERE type = inType
      AND value = inValue
    RETURNING *
  )
  INSERT INTO mytable
  (
    value,
    type
  )
  SELECT inValue, inType WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Barring upgrading to 9.5 so we can use built-in upsert functionality, how is it possible that a single statement like that could fail in that way?  (And can that be avoided?)

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)` is not atomic - there was even an article somewhere. I mean subquery is not atomic

Comment: @VaoTsun I'd love to know more if you have the article handy!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26970.1296761016%40sss.pgh.pa.us to start with. I think the artice was Craigs or someones of 2ndQ - looking myself - btw `UPSERT` itself is indeed atomic :)

Comment: sorry - just can't find it. but Tom Lane is cool enough already :) I'd try to use exception instead of subquery while waiting for 9.5

Comment: Just catch the exception at the application side and it is done.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto We already do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8316.1296788047%40sss.pgh.pa.us

> Re: isn't "insert into where not exists" atomic?
>
> No, it isn't: it
>
> **will** fail in the presence of other transactions doing the same thing... >
>
> AFAIR the basic alternatives are insert -> exception ->
>   update or taking a lock at the table level

(quoting very inaccurately - reading thread is highly recommended)

If I understand Toms directive right, before 9.5 `upsert`, the only option would be insert and if exception update or whatever...

Comment: Table level...ouch.